# How do I run a Team City Build Step only if a previous build step fails?

Tags: build, teamcity

I have a build step in my TeamCity build that should only run if the previous build step fails (the previous build step is an integration test run). Every guidance I have seen covers only how to run a build step only if no build steps have failed, which is offered through the TeamCity GUI.

I attempted to get support on this from Team City but have not gotten a response so I decided to post my question here.

Comment: It is a duplicate of the link psych provided. That is the only known way to accomplish what you want right now.

Comment: This is a duplicate. I am closing my question.